# Question regarding Nested Intervals(Real Analysis)

Tags: analysis

[image]

This is a question on the topic of Nested Intervals from the book "A first course in real analysis" by Sterling K. Berberian.

I understand the first part, we have to list all the rational numbers and there exists a bijection between the rational numbers and the natural numbers.

I don't understand the hint for the second part. I would really appreciate it if someone can explain to me, on an easy level, what the book is saying.

I don't understand the third part as well, mainly because I didn't get the second part.

Thank you.

Comment: In order to help you understand the proof, it would be nice if you would tell us *what* is Berberian trying to prove here.

Comment: I think that there exists a nested sequence of closed intervals such that no rational number is contained in them. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two disjoint intervals $I$, $\overline{I}$ there is no real number $r$ such that $r \in I \cap \overline{I}$. So, for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$, r must not belong to at least one of them .
Since $[0, \frac{1}{3}]$ and $[\frac{2}{3},1]$ are disjoint $r_1$ must not belong to at least one of them. So let $I_1 \in \{[0, \frac{1}{3}],[\frac{2}{3},1]\}$ be an interval such that $r_1 \notin I_1$. Now you have a set of the form $I_1=[a_1, b_1]$. Then define $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ for all $n > 1$ such that $I_n$ is the left or right third of $I_{n-1}$ and $r_n \notin I_n$. This choice is always possible because the left and right thirds are disjoint. Notice that the left and right thirds are subintervals of the original interval. So, by construction, $I_n \subset I_{n-1}$ for all $n > 1$ and $r_n \notin I_n$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then $(I_n)$ is a nested sequence of closed intervals such that $r_n \notin I_n$ for all $n \geq 1$.
Now we know by $2.6.1$ there is $a \leq b$ such that
$$
\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = [a,b].
$$
If $a <b$ there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q \in [a,b]$. Then
$$r_m=q \in [a,b]=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$$
for some $m \geq 1$ and this implies that $r_m \in I_m$. Since $r_m \notin I_m$ by construction, $a$ must be equal to b. Then $[a,b]=\{a\}$ and
$$
\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = [a,b]=\{a\}.
$$
And by the same reasoning $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Did you mean "for every r in Q" in the first line?

Comment: Notice that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. So It is true for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.